# Removing duplicates in feature layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, standard-license-level

I made a script to detect duplicate cables in a feature layer. The goal is to get duplicate cables and estimate the distance between them and their duplicates in the main layer to know if it's a real duplicate or just a reference error.

I managed to get the duplicate cables in the main layer. Now, I have a Feature Layer with duplicates in it. I would like to delete only the duplicate rows and create a layer. I have 10 cables in the layer and I would like to keep only 5 and delete the duplicates.

```
champ_a_verfier = ["REFERENCE", "OBJECTID"]
values = {}
values["Ref_Nulle"] = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(couche_cable, champ_a_verfier) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] in [None, ""]:
            values["Ref_Nulle"] += 1
        else:
            if r[0] not in values:
                values[r[0]] = 1
            else:
                values[r[0]] += 1
del rows

dictDoublons = {}
dictPasDoublons = {}
cable_cda = 'CDA'
count = 0
for item in values:
    if values[item] > 1:
        if not item.startswith("CDA"):
            dictDoublons[item] = 'Doublons'
            count += 1
            arcpy.AddWarning('Il y a {} cables en doublons  a Verifier / Corriger.'.format(count))
    else:
        dictPasDoublons[item] = 'PasDoublons'

# Recuperer les cables les plus proches des doublons
# Construction des élements nécessaires à la requête !
# construction de la chaine de caractère nécessaire a la requpete REFERENCE IN le but étant d'avoir  ("'CDI-47-GON2-097-1','CDI-47-GON2-097-1'")

liste_de_doublons = []
for key in dictDoublons:
    liste_de_doublons.append(key)
# mettre les doublons dans un tuple

tuple_doublons = tuple(liste_de_doublons)
# selection de tout les cables en doublons
for i in tuple_doublons:
    resultat_selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(couche_cable, "NEW_SELECTION","REFERENCE in ('{:s}')".format("','".join(liste_de_doublons)))

# création de la couche des cables selectionnées
resultat_selection_feature = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(resultat_selection)
```

Here is a picture of my result :

[image]

now I want to make a set on the cables, create a layer and estimate the distance to their duplicates in the main layer.
The cables > 5 m : are not real duplicates
cables < 0.02 cm : are real duplicates

Comment: How do you plan to measure distance between cables, may be a screen shot of a typical spatial arrangement in your data will help? Do your cables cross, therefore proximity distance is zero or do they run parallel or are they convergent or divergent, etc etc?

Comment: What level license are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm using a stadard licence of arcmap and Python 2.7

Comment: "The cables > 5 m : are not real duplicates cables < 0.02 cm : are real duplicates". Which field?

Comment: Field REFERENCE